# Can I have cross on my website which includes religions such as Christianity?

Tags: halal-haram, image

I am building a website that has various topics in it. One category is religion, and it has topics about various religions around the world. I want to create a topic about Christianity and I have to use an image of a cross near that topic. So is it okay if have it?

Comment: Yeah it is ok. It's the intention that counts in this case.